# How to modify values of a list using binding in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

What i want to achive is to save values added to a blank datagrid to a List. I have the following code in c#

```
public class HolidayCalendarView
{
   public List<HolidayCalendarDaysView> HolidayCalendarDays { get; set; }
}
```

HolidayCalendarDaysView class

```
public class HolidayCalendarDaysView
{
    public int HolidayID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DayToPlay { get; set; }
    public HolidayBehaviourType HolidayBehaviourType { get; set; }
}
```

My WPF Code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="selectedDatesGridView" 
          Grid.Column="2"  
          Width="140" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" 
          Margin="0,0,5,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn 
               Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.WordSelectedDates}" 
               Binding="{Binding DayToPlay, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"  
               Width="1.5*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I set in the constructor of the form:

```
this.selectedDatesGridView.ItemsSource = holidayCalendarView.HolidayCalendarDays;
```

When the user clicks a date in the calendar the date is added to the datagrid but not in the list

```
    private void holidayCalendarDays_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedDatesGridView.Items.Add((DateTime)holidayCalendarDays.SelectedDate);
        selectedDatesGridView.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

[image: When the user clicks a date in the calendar the date is added to the datagrid but not in the list]

How can i make it work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: try with `ObservableCollection<HolidayCalendarDaysView>` instead of `List<HolidayCalendarDaysView>`; unlike `List<>`, `ObservableCollection` notifies when items were added

Comment: @ASh nope didn't work, thanks

Comment: my thought was that selected date is added to `HolidayCalendarDays `collection, datagrid displays that collection, and calendar and datagrid don't communicate directly. i had to reread the question and -  `When the user clicks a date in the calendar the date is added to the datagrid` - how is this part implemented?

Comment: @ASh i've added the code for adding the selected date to the datagrid

Comment: a simple hack (but not a true wpf) would be to replace `holidayCalendarDays_SelectedDatesChanged` content with this code: `(selectedDatesGridView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<HolidayCalendarDaysView>).Add(new HolidayCalendarDaysView() { DayToPlay = (DateTime)holidayCalendarDays.SelectedDate} );`. itemsSource and grid should be updated

Comment: Please can you provide also the logic behind the adding of Dates to the datagrid ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this answer has to be a comment.

As @Ash suggested in his comment, use the observablecollection and one important thing to note is, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface where ever you exchange data between UI and Business Logic (hoping that you are using MVVM). Also set the ItemSource using a binding with mode set to twoway.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds it to the datagrid, but doesn't update the list.

Have a public property of type List, and have the datagrid content bind to it. 
Then add to that list. It MIGHT work, but you really want to use the ObservableCollection, which notifies of changes, so once the collection changes, you'll see the changes automatically (extra tip, it'll only do it on adding or removing items. If you change an item inside, you'll need to take care of refreshing it yourself :)

I'll try to give you some code in a min

This is from a project that's using MVVM Light, but the idea is the same.

In the xaml. Note the `ItemSource` and the binding.

```
<Grid ToolTip="Notice that the scrollview works inside the Grid.">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock >Example 1: ListBox with items inside a Grid: </TextBlock>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCol}"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Somewhere in a class:

```
public InnerControlViewModel()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
        MyCol = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"You are in design mode", "Next items are randomly generated:", " "};
    }
    else
    {
        MyCol = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "You are in runtime mode", "Next items are randomly generated:", " " };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        MyCol.Add("Random Date: " + RandomHelper.RandomDate());
    }

}

public ObservableCollection<string> MyCol { get; set; }
```

Note that in the constructor I create some fake data for the designer, and that in real time i get some random data.

The fact that it's an observable collection takes the brunt of updating things, and adding to it, will refresh the view as well.